# Android app should send edits to edit queue if necessary rather than rejecting them

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, android-app, api

I edited a question, on Stack overflow and when submitting preview, got red bar telling me my account isn't allowed to make suggested edits.  On the Sandbox android question it works fine, but that is editing an answer to my question.

The message I receive is:

> Account is not allowed to suggest edits

Are the rules for suggested edits different for Android app?

Comment: It would be nice if we had the exact error message and a link to the post you were *trying* to edit. There's a variety of factors that could affect whether you can edit a post.

Comment: Popup message is 'Account is not allowed to suggest edits'. I've seen this on the validation failed pages as well. There it is listed under "please fix the following"

Comment: @Kasra deep into the public beta of the app, is there any update?

Comment: Here's an idea: have the Edit link open the edit page on the mobile site for users with <2K rep. Ideally this should automatically log me in on my browser, but I don't mind having to manually log in.. As long as I can suggest an edit.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of version 1.0.54 (out for everyone now on Google Play) this is fixed.

---

As of version 1.0.53 (in beta, right now) we have suggested edit functionality and it happens seamlessly when you're editing but have to suggest instead.

---

I think I know what's happening here: The Stack Exchange API (which our official app also uses) doesn't offer the ability to submit your edits into an edit queue, so if you don't have enough reputation to flat out do an edit (in which case on the site you'd just be allowed to edit, but it'd go into the queue for validation), you get an error message.

If this is what happened, then you didn't do anything wrong it's just that our API doesn't have feature parity with the website yet, sorry about that.

Comment: Would be nice if the app realized that and told users that they can't suggest edits through the app, at least until the option *was* made available.

Comment: As it stands it does sound like a "You've been banned from...." message

Comment: @animuson Most definitely, and this was my main reason for originally having "Edit" only available for moderators and on your own question/answers but since most of the people in the alpha are high-rep users (who were asking for the feature) I decided to add it anyway. The app has a lot of issues that would be fixed if it knew more about user privileges, consider that [status-planned] for now.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi now that it's public most users are <2K so guess this should get higher priority.

Comment: Agreed; in addition, while my reputation on Stack Overflow is high enough to make edits, it is not so on other sites (and I run into the asker's issue)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi This issue is still present. It really would be nice if the message told you what was going on and directed you to click the "Open in browser" link instead!

Comment: Could you please tell us that we can't suggest edits before we start editing, rather than after we've typed it all for nothing?

Comment: @Gilles this is coming soon. The ability to check that (and to also submit suggested edits) was added to the API last week.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Was about to write a Meta question on MSE about this when a Suggested Question came up which linked to here. I'm a beta tester for the new SE Tablet app but haven't had a chance to test it yet; is this feature in the app?

Comment: @cybermonkey no, it will be in the next beta update though

Comment: Looks like this is not yet done, according to [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247631/unable-to-suggest-edits-from-the-android-app)? Guess that's why you still didn't mark it as [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @ShadowWizard the feature works fine in the tablet version which is in the alpha (v 1.0.54). I am an alpha tester now!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi would it be possible to remove "suggest edits" from per site meta, as the sites don't support edits?

Comment: @CRags Bah yes, forgot about that. Will fix in next update.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi [Any ideas?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257137/i-cant-suggest-edits-from-the-mobile-app)