# Cannot edit posts on iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app

When I try to submit an edit in the iOS app it returns this message:

> [image]

Text:

> Account is not allowed to suggest edits

What happened and can it be fixed please?

Comment: I'm uploading the picture later

Comment: On what site does it happen?

Comment: If site with less than 2K then [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208471/152859) is the same, as both the iOS app and android app use the same API.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, that appears to apply for this. Add it has an answer if you want.

Comment: Done, and also added a screenshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Starting at December 5<sup>th</sup> 2014, [this has been implemented/fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244657/152859). Kudos!**

---

As the error message hints, it's not really editing but rather *suggesting* an edit, meaning you don't have full edit privilege on that site.

The problem is that the Stack Exchange API simply does not support sending edits to the queue at the moment, as described nicely in [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208473/152859) to the [same report for android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208471/android-app-should-send-edits-to-edit-queue-if-necessary-rather-than-rejecting-t):

> The Stack Exchange API (which our official app also uses) doesn't offer the ability to submit your edits into an edit queue, so if you don't have enough reputation to flat out do an edit (in which case on the site you'd just be allowed to edit, but it'd go into the queue for validation), you get an error message.

When the API will support it, the app developers will add that feature at some point.

Comment: Aah - so it's the API that's causing this. Fascinating...

Comment: @bmike the apps are just a cover, the real "engine" is the API, yes.

Comment: Surely the resulting behaviour is not by design, even if the API doesn't support suggested edits. At least the message should say "This app does not support suggested edits." Better yet, don't offer the Edit button at all if the account does not have full editing privileges. Think of all the users' time wasted by this bug!

Comment: @200_success  That's the decision of the team, feel free to suggest this to Arie, you can `@-ping` him on the question as an editor.

Answer (score 7):

What has three digits and doesn't barf when you don't have full edit access? **Stack Exchange for iOS version 1.2.1!**

The new release of the app is snaking its ways through Apple's CDNs and onto you phone.  Expect to see it in the next 24 hours.  This has two key features for edits:

1. It actually checks whether or not you can edit/suggest an edit *before* you even get to the edit screen.  Can't edit?  No edit button.
2. If you can only suggest an edit, that's what it does!  Your edit goes into the suggested edit queue rather than being lost for all time.

Comment: Cooool, but as far as I know, anyone (even anonymous visitors) can suggest edits... or is it different in the app?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That varies from site to site on desktop. In the API permission based fields require an auth token so we're not showing at all for anonymous mode. For logged in but not registered on the site it looks like the API returns false for can_suggest_edit. In both cases we just hide the option so there's no unexpected data loss.

Comment: Looks like [it's not working anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246024/user-can-edit-question-directly-suggesting-an-edit-is-not-allowed-while-tryi)? :(