# Validate editor privileges before allowing edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

As a followup to [Cannot edit posts on iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225138/260913), I'd like to request that there is some permissions validation that's done before a user is able to enter the Edit page for a question

I just spent 10 minutes fixing a question via the iOS app, only to submit it and have all that work be discarded because I wasn't able to make edits. If there was a simple, automated privileges check before going into the edit page, I would have saved myself the time spent editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now available in the iOS app.  The edit button will only appear if you can actually submit an edit.  Also suggested edits have been enabled so you can still submit something even if you don't have full edit privileges.

Comment: Thanks, now [this old request of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225160/dont-show-the-edit-option-when-i-cant-really-edit-mobile-apps) is half completed. Do you have any idea if the android app team plan a similar feature?

Comment: @ShadowWizard We were just looking at that.  It's gonna be in the next beta build.

Comment: You mean next beta build of the android app? If so, care to post answer on my request as well and mark as completed? :-)

Comment: I'll leave that to Kasra.  Before I saw [tag:android-app] I was going to mark it as a dupe.

Comment: Very heroic of you! ;)

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks for the quick turnaround!