# I can't suggest edits

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, ios-app

I've got 364 rep, but I can't suggest edits when I'm in iPhone app. I don't know if I can suggest edits when I go to the computer/full version, though.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225138/cannot-edit-posts-on-ios-app

Comment: I see. Should I delete the post now?

Comment: I don't think so. But it will be marked as dupe anyway.