# 'user can edit question directly, suggesting an edit is not allowed.' while trying to edit another user's post?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app

Whenever I attempt to edit another user's question I get an error using the iOS app:

> user can edit question directly, suggesting an edit is not allowed.

What's the reason for this error? I'm not intending to make the suggestion just to edit.

Comment: Happens to me as well.

Comment: You need 2k reputation to edit, until then all you can do is suggest edits.

Comment: However, this should be possible according to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244657/152859), so looks like a regression.

Comment: Looking at this.  The app gets flags from the question `can_edit` and `can_suggest_edit` which it uses to either the edit or suggest edit API endpoint.  Either the app is screwing up or the wrong privilege information is coming from the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed. When fetching questions the API was checking for privileges based on the SO rep requirements rather than the individual site's requirements.  Submission on the other hand used the site's rep requirements, causing the mismatch.  For Biology, this affected users between 1000 and 2000 rep.

Comment: I think users should get significant or (some at least) points for initiating what results in API corrections. Just an opinion. Thanks for fixing this all