# Popup privilege information before posting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications, android-app, post-ban

My account is blocked in Stack Overflow from posting questions. I found the bug that Stack Exchange Android application accepts questions even from blocked users. It is rectified now.

I have a suggestion: Can you show the blocked notification before I start typing a question in Android application? I typed a very long question using my mobile application, but when I try posting, it says you are blocked.

Comment: A bit related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208471/android-app-should-send-edits-to-edit-queue-if-necessary-rather-than-rejecting-t. Basically, anything that needs warning *before* you do something you can't from the app **should** be shown to prevent user's frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this isn't supported by our API, a post-ban is only checked when actually attempting to submit a post. Since this is quite an edge case, I'm planning on leaving this as-is, I would expect people who are post-banned to know they are post-banned. If it ends up happening more frequently than expected, I'll take another look.