# Unable to suggest edits from the Android App

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

First of all, I'd like to say that the new roll out of the SE app for Android is great. Love the rich formatting and editing features.

The problem I have been having is that every time I try to suggest edits to someone's questions, I am prompted "the user is not allowed to suggest edits" even though I am in the desktop/web versions of SE. Why is this?

#### update:

I was able to suggest edit on the title and/or tags of qurstions, just not the body. How come?

Comment: I see. It is an api issue. The api does not support it yet. Thanks for the link @ShadowWizard

Comment: Actually the API does support this and as far as I know it's possible to suggest edits via the iOS app, but the android app might be bit behind in implementing the functionality.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you. As long as the issue is out there for the devs to see.

Comment: update:

I was able to suggest edit on the title and/or tags of qurstions, just not the body. How come?

Comment: Weird... might be new bug then. Hopefully the dev would look into it soon enough. :)

Comment: @kartikg3 the alpha android app in the making allows a person to suggest edits, and it works!

Comment: What version of the app are you using? We used 1.0.54 yesterday which fixes this.