# Let me know in advance that I can't suggest an edit on a specific answer in the app

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, android-app

When viewing an answer that already has a suggested edit on it, I get the option to edit it via the app. After typing bunch of text and submitting, I get a message saying that I can't suggest edits, and can't actually submit the edit.

In the desktop version, the "edit" link is greyed out. Can I get that in the Android App too? This happens too often for me.

This applies to editing answers only.

Comment: Related: [Android app should send edits to edit queue if necessary rather than rejecting them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208471/21960)

Comment: This got nothing with low reputation. It means there is other edit pending, or you are banned from suggesting edits due to history of bad edits. The app does not, and probably can't, check this in advance, and it only gets it from the server after submitting the edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, it's just my low reputation on that site. On the Desktop version the `edit` button is not working.

Comment: You are wrong. Even 1 rep user can suggest edits in any site. Try reading about suggested edits if you don't believe someone with years of experience in this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, it took some time to realize it. I was trying to edit an answer, not a question.

Comment: No worry, glad you realized it. :) Anyway, no difference between editing or suggesting edits to questions or answers, it's exactly the same.