# Delete questions/answers in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, ios-app, vote-to-delete

There is currently no way to delete questions or answers in the iOS app, even with the required Trusted User privilege. We can *edit* and *vote*, but not delete.

Can this option please be added to the app?

Comment: Think it's dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216962/152859) as it's cross app request, dependant on the API to support it first.

Comment: Possibly. I could suggest the linked question add ios-app tag, but the date of implementation may be different, so it seems an isolated feature request.

Comment: I defer to the developers to weigh in on *how* they want these issues posted. One big one to stay concise, or different ones as a metric of priority

Comment: Yeah, guess we better leave it as two separate requests.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The API does have the necessary method (at least now)

Comment: @TimStone oh, so it's bit weird they didn't add such option yet, isn't it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, I don't know what the reason is, at least for the Android app. I assume the iOS app just needs more time to get that less commonly used functionality in place.

Comment: Posting them separately is fine.

Comment: @boltclock, they're *flagging* for you to delete their answers for them when they could just do that from their browser? gawd.

Comment: @mhlester: To be fair, if you're posting from mobile, chances are you don't have immediate access to a desktop browser. And switching to the mobile site just to delete answers is cumbersome. Reviewers aren't all that smart either - leaving canned comments without paying any attention to context.

Comment: Taking another look at this.

Comment: Well played @ShadowWizard

Comment: I can only hope

Comment: Taking another look at this ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess we're blind? It's already there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete your own answers or questions. Unfortunately, the API doesn't provide a way to do general deletion, so we can't get it in the app yet.

Apologies for the delay here -- I have recently moved over to working on the Careers team, so this question was orphaned for a bit.

Comment: Um, how did you go back in time and insert it in the build I already have installed?

Comment: It was there all along. Or "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

Comment: i cannot delete my own answer (we’ll certainly i can’t find a way to do it). i’m told i need to join the stack. why can i answer a question without joining a particular stack but not delete my own (accidental) answer. i meant it as a comment in response to another comment  not an answer