# Cannot delete answer

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, vote-to-delete

It seems that you cannot delete an answer from the iOS app.

Is this be design or overlooked?

For the benefit of those with the privileges heres a post I needed to delete: [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230358/238300)

Comment: Related: [Allow us to vote to delete from the app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-app)

Comment: @hichris123, OP doesn't need to *vote* to delete own answer. The original tags were correct.

Comment: @mhlester It's the same thing: when editing/deleting your own post, *your "vote" is binding*.

Comment: Then why is [tag:delete] incorrect?

Comment: @mhlester Delete is kinda an ambiguous tag... and it doesn't really describe the *process* of deleting a post.

Comment: Hmm, the tag wiki seems to describe users deleting their own posts. I'd agree with keeping both vote-to-delete and delete, but don't know I'd lose delete entirely...

Comment: I am only interested in deleting personally.

Comment: @mhlester Meta (aka MSE now) got its quirks, such tags are among those quirks, and I agree with hichris on this. The proper action being requested is vote to delete, which is missing in the app.

Comment: @AshleyMedway as a work around, you can still flag from the app, choose "Other" and explain you're using the app thus can't delete it by yourself.

Comment: Maybe the tags should just be synonymized. delete has more posts than vote-to-delete, but if it's never the right choice...