# Allow us to vote to reopen from the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, vote-to-reopen

Currently, the only way to vote to reopen in the Android app is to open the post in a browser, and then vote to reopen from there.

Can we get reopen vote functionality within the app?

<sup>Related: [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/)</sup>

Comment: +1 - Worth noting that the mobile website allows reopening, as does the SE API, so I see no reason for not doing this. Having to open my browser is annoying..

Comment: @JonasCz really? Didn't see it in the documentation? https://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=type#docs