# Can't flag questions as Too Broad from the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, android-app

I can't seem to choose to make a 'Too Broad' flag from the Android app. I think that there should be the same flag options as the Web application.

Comment: Does this just affect the 'Too Broad' option, or can you not flag at all?

Comment: There are 3 options

Comment: Which are... You need to tell us so we can fix it.

Comment: Spam, rude, and moderator  assistance

Comment: Have you considered that the question may already be closed? What question is it? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I will go back and double checked

Comment: Thanks I just saw that it was "put on hold as off topic " thanks

Comment: How can I delete this question from my phone

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza unfortunately, [you can't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app) :( (and you really can't delete this question since the answer is already upvoted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is closed, you can't close it again. Therefore, you only have three options to flag a post:

- Spam/Abusive
- Rude/Offensive
- Custom Mod flags

This is keeping with the web UI, and is not a bug. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)