# Can't I delete a question (post) using the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Tags: feature-request

I tried deleting a post from my Stack Exchange account. But I could not find any place to delete it. Can't I delete any post when I am using the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Comment: That is true, neither of the apps allow deleting a post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard According to [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app#comment913560_281120), iOS app does.

Comment: @Alex so it means it's not API limitation, just design. Makes sense, as I always said there's no developer for the android app for years now. It became a sad joke. I am just amazed SE didn't shut it down earlier.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's a bit of both. The API supports deletion of __own__ [questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-question) and [answers](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-answer) only. The iOS app exposes this feature, the Android app does not.