# Android App Missing Delete Functionality?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Is the Android app missing the feature to delete your own posting, or am I missing it?

I've seen [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app) and agree with it **but** that is about voting to delete, I'm talking about deleting ones own answers/questions.

I also tried to post a comment stating I was going to delete the answer I made but that also failed to post.

Comment: Actually you also vote to delete your own question when you do that. It's just that your vote as the owner of the post is binding. So... It's a duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: @Elias well it's **exact** dupe of something else, which is dupe of the mentioned question. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The dupe you linked to was already a dupe lol. You could've skipped all steps and link to the very original, rather than chain of dupes.

Comment: @Unitato I could, but wanted exact dupe as it's more clear this way.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The dup is almost 4 years old and it seems to have had no progress or definitive status set to it. Should I put a bounty on it or when do the SO engineers look at a particular ticket/request?

Comment: @chris85 no point in bounty, even if by some miracle [the apps will survive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299894/152859), they will never add delete functionality to the android app, I'm 1000% sure of that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, okay, thanks for the link.