# Deleting my own answers or questions in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, support, android-app

**Although I am not asking to be able to vote for other's posts to be deleted, this question is related to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281120)**.

**NOTE** - **Answer, not question**, so it is not an "exact duplicate of this question".

I currently use the Android version and so I don't know if this applies to iOS, but there seems to be no facility to delete your own questions or answers within the mobile app. Can we have that added please? If it is there, how do we do it?

As an example if I click "more" on this question,

> [image: Screen capture of this question]

I can open the question in my browser or flag it for deletion by moderators:

> [image: Screen capture of options in "more"]

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I am not asking to vote to delete others posts.  I am asking to be able to delete my own posts.

Comment: That question is about own posts as well. Deleting your own post is technically voting to delete it - except your vote is binding. Also, the top answer mentions deleting own posts.

Comment: Here on Meta Stack Exchange, the guidelines for closing questions as duplicates are much broader. Also, even though deleting one's own post and voting to delete someone else's post are semantically different actions, they are still the same action *internally* (in fact, if you mouse over the delete button on your own post, it will say "vote to delete this post"). Also, I edited the duplicate target to make it more clear that it's also related to deleting one's own posts.

Comment: This is the point here.  I am on my mobile and cannot even "mouse over the delete button" and as commented in the "dupe post" it can be done in iOS app but not android.

Comment: Let me make this even more clear: that question asks to allow voting to delete *all* posts (that one can vote to delete based on rep), including one's own posts. When you delete your own post, it's treated by the system as casting a vote to delete it (as it works on other posts). The exception is, as the author, your vote is binding and takes place immediately. Want proof of that? Just open up the site on a desktop computer and see that the "delete" button shows "vote to delete this post" on mouseover. Finally, development on the Android apps is currently on hiatus.