# Loading the question failed for the deleted question in my feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

When I opened my feed, and clicked on some question with comment that I've made - it displayed "**Loading the question failed**". I've clicked retry a couple of times, but it didn't help.

Also I've tried to to close application from settings, and try again, but it still reproduces.

Here is that question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353812/internal-alias-for-methods-in-c-sharp. 
Seems it's already deleted, but it still shows in Android App Feed.

I suppose as the question is deleted by the author, it shouldn't be displayed in my Feed.

And also when I click to reply icon for it. once it crashed app. I've send a report in Android.

**App Version:** 1.0.1

**Android Version:** 4.4.2

[image: My Feed]

[image: Question loading failed]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195262/make-loading-the-question-failed-error-more-descriptive. It's bothered me for a while. I have a feeling it's due to the backend API, not the app.

Comment: I didn't used their API, but anyway I supose the app can filter deleted answers on app side. But it depends do users need to get Deleted questsions via API. If yes, then it's App issue

Comment: This is still happening in version 1.0.27