# Menu button turns into back button on Android app's Feed page

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I found a bug in the Android app where if you attempt to load a question from the Feed that doesn't exist, the menu button (the one at the top-left with three horizontal bars) becomes a back button, making the menu inaccessible until reloading the app. Furthermore, while in this state, attempting to refresh the feed will always result in an error.

Version: 1.0.83

Screenshot after clicking a non-existent question:

[image: navigating back on feed.. to where?]

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I have no idea what you mean. There is no menu button in your screenshot, it's just a screenshot of what appears to be ordinary feeds list.

Comment: I'm referring to the button at the top left of the screenshot. Normally it should be a menu button (the one with three horizontal bars), but instead has become a back button (denoted by a back arrow). In this state it is impossible for me to access the standard menu without exiting the app first.

Comment: Oh, I see now. And what happens if you tap other question?

Comment: Anyway, what you *should* see is error message: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217715/loading-the-question-failed-for-the-deleted-question-in-my-feed

Comment: What version of the app is this?

Comment: It looks like my feed got refreshed and it no longer has any non-existent questions, so I can't test it anymore. @BrianNickel: I'm using 1.0.83; I feel silly for not including that, and there's a chance it may have been updated since posting this.

Comment: There's a similarity to opening question from HnQ widget, the *Menu* button (3-horizontal line) will be replaced by *Back* button (arrow), but no crash. You can still access the menu by swiping from left screen though.