# Less generic error message when post is removed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

**Using Stack Exchange iOS App version 1.1.0.101**

I post a comment on a question.  The OP replies and then removes the question.

I get a notification about the reply.

When following the link from my notification on the *website* I get the following *helpful* message:

> "Page not found.  This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

While in the *iOS app* I get the following *unhelpful* message:

> "Error.  The question could not be loaded".

Feature request:

Please make the iOS error message less generic.  Ideally it should match the error message given on the website.  As written it is very hard to tell if the error is due to a server issue, a network issue or what...

Comment: [You can take a look at a similar post on the Android side I posted long long ago.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195262/make-loading-the-question-failed-error-more-descriptive) From my research, it isn't an issue with the app. It's a limitation of the API. Hopefully reposting it for the iOS app will refocus some attention on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we can't say for certain that the question was deleted *by author* or deleted at all, that error only shows up if the API successfully responds to our request with zero questions.

As such I'm taking the lowest common denominator text from the 404 page:

> "Question Not Found. We're sorry, we couldn't find the question you requested."

Not as informative as the web, but it stings a lot less than the current one.

This will show up in the next build.