# Allow seeing deleted questions in app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, deleted-questions

I just passed the 10k threshold on SO.

Unfortunately though, I can't view deleted questions in the app! I get the standard "... this question make have been deleted" popup.

Even if it's not considered worth it to allow actually viewing the questions in the app, it would be nice if it instead opened the link in a browser or something, or gave a more appropriate error message.

Comment: There's already a request for a more appropriate error message [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195262/323179).

Comment: @Laurel yeah, over the years everything has been requested, and nothing was done. Too bad it's now too late, and nothing will ever be added. (both iOS app and android app are officially frozen.)

Comment: @Laurel I searched using the search in the app instead of Google.  That probably didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Frozen? But there's so many little things that would likely take them so little time to implement, but would make a huge difference. Please tell me they're not investing time in that awful SO app.

Comment: Oh, nvm. This is an API issue. Guess they can't get that working easily :/

Comment: @Carcigenicate read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, I'll give it a read.